# robocopy using secfix to fix permissions of ONLY subdirectories, excluding root directory

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2, robocopy

I have a rather interesting issue that I think is logically possible via Robocopy, but I cannot find the correct syntax to accomplish this goal.

**Problem**:

I am trying to sync a lot of data via two remote shares.  IE: robocopy "\share1\root" "\share2\root" /MIR /SECFIX /SEC /S /E /R:5 /W:2 /MT:64

The issue arises due to the fact that the root directory has different permissions than all of the subdirectories.  I have close to 1000 subdirectories that makes this tedious and difficult to manually do.

**Current Issue**

Running 'robocopy "\share1\root" "\share2\root" /MIR /SECFIX /SEC /S /E /R:5 /W:2 /MT:64' changes ONLY the permissions of the root directory, but not the subdirectories.

Running 'robocopy "\share1\root\subdirectory1" "\share2\root\subdirectory1" /MIR /SECFIX /SEC /S /E /R:5 /W:2 /MT:64' DOES result in the desired state, but is far too tedious to do for over 1000 sub directories

**Desired Results**

Either a robocopy command that would ONLY change the permissions on the subdirectories (and the child elements within those directories) but maintain the perms on the root directory, or another means of accomplishing the above.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can technically use PowerShell to automate looping through your directory tree.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path '\share1\root' -Directory | Foreach-Object {
    robocopy "\share1\root\$($_.Name)" "\share2\root\$($_.Name)" /MIR /SECFIX /SEC /S /E /R:5 /W:2 /MT:64
}
```